# how do i bind menuitem.click to a command in a different view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, menu

I have a contextmenu, the itemsource is bound to an observable collection
i need to bind the MenuItem.Click to a command in my viewmodel..
HOW DO I DO THIS?

i have my own view model but the context menu items should be bounded to a different viewmodel..

Comment: You can bind to a Path (to the command) can't you?  Like `MainVm.SubVm.MyCommand`

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor to get to your parent Usercontrol and bind to the Path=DataContext.YourCommand. I believe you are trying to bind to the containing control's viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont like using RelativeSource, you can name your parent element and then using `ElementName` tag in the Binding extension:

If you want to bind between/cross different ViewModels, i believe you will have to use some sort of Event Broker/Aggregator. Have a look at Prism, it might give you some ideas